# LoadError when executing ruby code in /etc/rc.d/rc.local

Tags: ruby, require

I use CentOS 6.6. I want to execute a Ruby code on startup, so I added the following command to execute the code to /etc/rc.d/rc.local.

```
ruby /ruby/send_mail.rb
```

In send_mail.rb, there is **require 'mail'**, but error occurred like the following.

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- mail (LoadError)
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /ruby/send_mail:23:in `<main>'
```

(I got this error by using **ruby /ruby/send_mail.rb &> error_output**)

I did **gem install mail.** And "send_mail.rb" works properly when I run this manually. Would you tell me what I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running ruby using the RVM wrappers, as described [here](https://rvm.io/deployment/cron):

```
/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.2.2/ruby /ruby/send_mail.rb
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I used RVM wrappers, and the error has gone.